# How to replace several values in cells in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel table as :

ABC 01th,02th,03th,04th
BCD 26th,02th
CVF 01th

Expected output
ABC 01st,02nd,03rd,04th
BCD 26th,02nd
CVF 01st

I have tried this code but it is replacing if only that single value is present in cell. I need to repalce all the wrong values in cell with new values. Can anyone help with this.

```
   from xlrd import open_workbook
   import xlsxwriter
   rb = open_workbook("Dates.xlsx")
   wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Updated_Workbook1.xlsx')
   ws = wb.add_worksheet()
   s_orig = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
   NEW_Values= {'01th': '01st', 
        '02th': '02nd', 
        '03th': '03rd',
        '21th': '21st',
        '22th':'22nd',
        '23th':'23rd',
        '31th':'31st'}
    for row in range(s_orig.nrows):
        for col in range(s_orig.ncols):
            if s_orig.cell(row,col).value in NEW_Values:
        # s.write(row, col, NEW_Values[item])
                ws.write(row, col, NEW_Values[s_orig.cell(row,col).value])
            else:
                ws.write(row, col, s_orig.cell(row,col).value)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: Which code? also what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion: This

```
import re

NEW_Values= {'01th': '01st', '02th': '02nd', '03th': '03rd', '21th': '21st',
             '22th': '22nd', '23th': '23rd', '31th': '31st'}
re_new_values = re.compile(r'|'.join(NEW_Values))
def repl(match):
    return NEW_Values[match.group()]

value = "ABC 01th,02th,03th,04th BCD 26th,02th CVF 01th"
print('Before:', value)
value = re_new_values.sub(repl, value)
print('After :', value)
```

will result in

```
Before: ABC 01th,02th,03th,04th BCD 26th,02th CVF 01th
After : ABC 01st,02nd,03rd,04th BCD 26th,02nd CVF 01st
```

which looks like your expected output. `r'|'.join(NEW_Values)` produces the pattern `01th|02th|03th|21th|22th|23th|31th` which works in the regex search like `'01th' or '02th' or ... or '31th'`. And the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.sub) method is using the `repl` function to replace the matches in `value` via the mapping `NEW_Values`.

If I haven't made any mistakes then this could be a way to fit that into your program:

```
import re
...

NEW_Values= {'01th': '01st', '02th': '02nd', '03th': '03rd', '21th': '21st',
             '22th': '22nd', '23th': '23rd', '31th': '31st'}
re_new_values = re.compile(r'|'.join(NEW_Values))
def repl(match):
    return NEW_Values[match.group()]

for row in range(s_orig.nrows):
    for col in range(s_orig.ncols):
        ws.write(row, col, re_new_values.sub(repl, s_orig.cell(row,col).value))

wb.close()
```

**PS**: You could also use a throw-away `lambda` fuction:

```
        ws.write(row, col, re_new_values.sub(lambda m: NEW_Values[m.group()],
                                             s_orig.cell(row,col).value))
```